# not a able to submit multiple forms with jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am new bee in jquery and javascript. I am trying to submit multiple forms using jquery. My requirement is when user submits anyone of the multiple forms, all the forms data should be submitted to the url . my forms are like

```
<form id="vendors_select_form">
    <button type="submit">Search</button> 
</form>
<form id="search_form"> </form>
<button type="submit">Submit</button> 
<form id="vendors_select_form">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

and the jquery that I am using is

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("form button[type='submit']").click(function() {
        // Construct data string
        var dataString = $("#vendors_select_form, #sort_select_form, #search_form").serialize();
        $form=$('#search_form')

        // Log in console so you can see the final serialized data sent to AJAX
        console.log(dataString);

        // Do AJAX
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'GET',
            //method:'GET',
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/ksaprice/product_search",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                //alert(data)
                //console.log(data);
                //$('#message').html(data);
                //$('search_form').submit();
            }
        });
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

dataString gets the data from all the forms, but this data string is not getting submitted to the url. please help.

Comment: are you sure that `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ksaprice/product_search` is reachable? have you tried logging anything on the server page?

Comment: Why don't you use only one form???

Comment: @AbdoAdel yes i could able to reach the link [link](http://127.0.0.1:8000/ksaprice/product_search/?q=iphone&select_vendor=Extra&sory_by=relevance)

Comment: @A.Wolff I am consdidering that, I would be better for my we app to be able to submit multiple forms to one target at once..

Comment: @A.Wolff is it possible to submit all the data from different buttons in a single form at once, when anyone of the button is submitted?, please let me know..

Comment: yes, You can have multiple submit buttons and any submit button in the form will submit the entire form. * button should be inside the form. TRY TO GO WITH A SINGLE FORM

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks using one form now..

Comment: @kumaDK thanks for the confirmation, it help..